# Como hacer que la cámara funcione en una web desde webview en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview-android

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la cámara del móvil funcione en una web que se ve a través del WebView?

He probado el código siguiente en versiones SDK 4.4 (Kitkat), 5.0 (Lollipop) y 6.0 (Marshmallow):

#### ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml (permisos -> Internet/Cámara):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

#### MainActivity.java:

```
package net.addingplus.webview6;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(""); //Web a la que hay que ir
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Me abre la web, puedo navegar por ella pero no me deja hacer fotos, me aparece el icono de reproducir un vídeo pero no hace nada.

No tengo mucha experiencia en Android Studio, agradeceré las respuestas que intenten aportar ayuda, pero cuanto más específico sea, mejor :-).

Comment: Acá te dejo un video de como se hace https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8XF3AfXrkY

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo utilizo la camara de mi app y utilizo los siguiente permisos en el Manifest:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva. :)

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, lo he probado pero no funciona.
He probado con lo que has puesto y a más con otros ejemplos que no me han funcionado con estos otrso permisos:
INTERNET///CAMERA///WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE///READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE///ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE///
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest"></uses-permission>

Comment: He añadido en el manifest --> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"></uses-feature> pero sigo sin conseguirlo, he seguido pasos del video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYeVXGNG-b4