# Ocultar ventana de URL Chrome del móvil

Tags: java, android-studio, iphone, chrome

Quisiera saber como ocultar la parte de superior del navegador web de Google Chrome.
Por código desde Android Studio o como se pueda ya que se trata de una web que se abre al abrir una app.

Necesito que de una app me abra una web como si fuera una app, que la pantalla entera sea para la "aplicación", que no se vea la parte de superior de Chrome (el botón de house, la url, botón de ventanas abiertas y de mas opciones)

Lo conseguí con WebView pero entonces tengo otro problema que ya he preguntado ([Como hacer que la cámara funcione en una web desde webview en android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226059/como-hacer-que-la-c%C3%A1mara-funcione-en-una-web-desde-webview-en-android-studio)).

Necesito o que se active la cámara desde WebView cuando la web lo requiere o que no se vea la parte superior de Crhome.

Feliz fin de año.

Comment: intenta agregar mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient()); a tu web view, con eso deberia bastar. Y crea tu CustomWebChromeClient extendiendo de WebChromeClient

Comment: Si deseas usar tu móvil simulando un usuario desde tu android studio te recomiendo usar [tag:selendroid]